How do I tell partman-auto where to install Debian 12 using preseed.cfg?
Important note, I cannot use external media in this situation. I am trying to use preseeding to automatically install Debian 12 onto my device. This device is running CentOS 7 with an LVM and is using xfs. The LVM has three logical volumes, home, root, and swap, with no empty space. I want to automatically install Debian into the root volume so that I can access important files in the home volume. I can do this manually through the Debian installer by choosing manual partitioning, selecting the LVM root volume, using it as Ext4, and mounting it at /. However, I can't figure out how to do this automatically using partman-auto. Here is the partitioning section of my preseed.cfg file
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/centos_lvm_group/root 
d-i partman-auto/method string regular 
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select deb-root
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                         \ 
deb-root ::                                             \ 
6000 8000 10000 ext4                            \ 
$primary{ } $bootable{ }            \
method{ format } format{ }      \        
use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \ 
mountpoint{ / }                         \
d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true 
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish 
d-i partman/confirm boolean true 
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
When attempting to automatically install Debian using this configuration, I get the error:
no root file system is defined please correct this from the partitioning menu

I'm very new to all of this, so I may have used the wrong terminology or missed some crucial steps. I would love to learn, so if I've made any mistakes, please correct me!
